# Ubuntu 20.04 create user with access to a single directory

Tags: ssh, 20.04, sftp

I created an Ubuntu 20.04 server and I want to create a user with SSH and SFTP access to a single directory, which will be the root of that user’s web directory.

I added the user using

```
sudo useradd -d /mnt/volume_nyc1_01/html/www mcl06
sudo passwd mcl06
```

SSH and SFTP ok, but he can browse the top directories, I want to limit access to only that directory and subfolders

mcl06:mcl06 on www

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: I don't found solution official in ubuntu, but in CentOS, its working default great way. I am as well digging for same.